# How to alter response headers from module hook

Tags: 8, files, event-subscribers

I am puzzled how to alter the response headers from specific hook (hook_file_download)?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 */
function example_file_download($uri) {
  $scheme = FileSystem::uriScheme($uri);
  if ($scheme === 'public') {
// Set custom headers here.
  }

}
```

Basically I want under certain conditions to set additional headers and in D7 this would happen with drupal_add_http_header() but in D8 as far as I can see this can happen only by implementing custom subscriber and using getSubscribedEvents and then KernelEvents. However this does not solve my case as I want to add custom headers only for specific file types.

If I use custom subscriber then this would be possible by:

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
$events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = ['exampleFunc'];

return $events;
}
```

And then:

```
/**
* 
*/
public function exampleFunc(FilterResponseEvent $event) {

$response->headers->set('Header', 'Value');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in D7 this would happen with drupal_add_http_header()

In other hooks that might have been true, but `hook_file_download` works the same in Drupal 8 as it did in Drupal 7, without using `drupal_add_http_header`.

This is the documentation for both versions’ return value from that hook:

> If the user does not have permission to access the file, return -1. If the user has permission, **return an array with the appropriate headers**. If the file is not controlled by the current module, the return value should be NULL.

Emphasis mine.

You can't get access to the response object in `hook_file_download`, because it doesn't exist yet. It's not created until after the hook is invoked in [`FileDownloadController::download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21FileDownloadController.php/function/FileDownloadController%3A%3Adownload/8.6.x). The headers you return are added to the response, so returning a suitable key-value array from the hook is the way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but the problem is not with hook_file_download itself. Basically what Im trying to do is to add `$response->headers->set('HEADER', 'value');` from hook_file_download() but I cant figure out how to use the response object from there.

Comment: The response doesn't exist at that point - it's created after the invocation. See [`FileDownloadController::download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21FileDownloadController.php/function/FileDownloadController%3A%3Adownload/8.6.x). The key-value array of headers you return from `hook_file_download` are added to the response, so it's essentially the same op

Comment: I can't believe how I missed this even when you bolded it in the answer... Thank you very much, let me know where I can send you a beer!

Comment: You're welcome, and don't worry about the beer - I've already had waaaay too much guinness tonight, let's just pretend you bought me one of those ;)